# Posting keys to notepad using win32api doesn't work

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, win32gui

Here's my code to send the keys from the string "Hello world" .
I have an instance of notepad open, proof is that the string "found" is printed, but nothing appears on my notepad.

Any ideas ?

```
import win32con
import win32api
import win32gui

def enumHandler(hwnd, lParam):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        if 'Notepad' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
            print 'found'
            for c in "Hello World\n":
                win32api.PostMessage(
                                    hwnd,
                                    win32con.WM_CHAR,
                                    ord(c),
                                    0)

win32gui.EnumWindows(enumHandler, None)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are sending the messages to the main Notepad window. That's the top-level window that has the caption bar. The messages will be processed by the EDIT control that is a child of the top level window. You can only make this work by sending the messages there.

However, I'm sure that your real problem is different from faking keyboard input to the Notepad program. And your real problem is most likely best solved a different way. Windows provides UIAutomation for the purpose of automating applications. That is most likely the right solution to your actual problem.

Comment: Yep that's right. What library would you recommend for UIAutomation in Windows ? Links to documentation would be appreciated too.

Comment: UIAutomation is a COM library and you can easily enough drive COM using Python. UIAutomation is well documented on MSDN.

Comment: Can you please create a simple example using the UIAutomation library that does what my code intended to do ? That would be great :-)

Comment: Sorry, I've never done it from Python. It would take me ages to do what you ask. However, a bit of websearch should give you much better results. For instance: http://www.google.com/webhp?#q=UIAutomation+python  Lots of good stuff there. For example: https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/  But there's loads more good stuff out there. Really, you don't want to mess around faking input. That's just horrid!

Comment: ok, I found pywinauto but it's not very well supported (doesn't work on 64 bits, has dependencies that can't be found). I found this: https://github.com/billagee/test-polyglot/blob/master/printDesktopUiaElementName/ms-ui-automation-com-api/python/comtypes/print_desktop_uia_element_name.py which is an example of using UIAutomation COM library